# Would you give up a good internship for a full time startup job offer?

Tags: work-experience

First time on the forum. First of all, I'm a new graduate.

When I say good internship, I mean an internship in a reputable company. For instance, national public health corporation, government agencies, etc... It would definitely look good on my resume.

Now I've got few startup who contacted me. Obviously, their name on my resume won't look as good as the corp in which I'm doing an internship right now. But, getting a full time position after the internship MAY be hard since my reputable corporate does not have a flexible hiring policy. There might be some part time jobs.

Also startups jobs are not offering jobs I was first looking for (I mean by that if I'm a programmer, they say come program in Java though I like C++ better, or if I like finance they say come do some Accounting although I like Accounting  audits...)

So what would you do if startups contact you in this position ? I was thinking about keep my internship the longest I can until I get a really reasonable offer (hopefully from a well established corporate)...

What would **you** do?  I know it looks like a subjective question so I was wondering how to avoid starting a career from the wrong foot and later having a resume showing inconsistency...

Comment: just keep your internship while you look for new offers. Your question is likely to get closed as you're asking for advice, btw. I would suggest working in a good startup as a way to get exposure to different business divisions, which will help you consolidate what you want to do in the future. The care you should have then is the startup funding, who the funding groups are, the experience of the leadership, and of course if you're interested in what the startup is doing.

Comment: Are you paid well in your current internship?

Comment: @DarkMatter Nope... We can consider I'm not.

Comment: It's funny how people are voting up and down this question... At some point I was +2 (vote up). I guess it means the question is maybe *off topic* therefore *put on hold* but it's a damn interesting question though. Up to 3 answers (who also got voted up numerous times).... To all thos who put my question *on hold* : you guys are robots lol ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Based on **my experience** as a hiring manager, most of the time a **paying** job will look better on a resume.  It typically is **better for you too** in that you will be expected **to produce**, which is a good habit for you to get into and you earn cash.

Unless you are interning for say Google, Apple, or Microsoft for example take a job that **pays**.  Experience that earns you a paycheck is more valuable in my view that other types of experience.

I would **not** however *work for free at a start up* versus taking an internship.  That just looks and sounds silly.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, it also depends on the length of the internship. There will pretty much always be start-ups looking for fresh graduates. It might be best to complete the internship and rely that similar opportunities in start-ups will exist after it too.

Comment: @Sopuli I like your point. The internship is pretty much lasting... Almost a year now

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are doing an internship now and you have a few startups contacting you if you want to interview for a job. Until you have a job offer in your hands, an opportunity to interview is not a guarantee that you'll get the job. I wouldn't quit your internship just to pursue interviewing with a startup.

I would inquire at your current company if there is a internship-to-hire possibility at the end of your internship. If not, you basically have a limited term contract position and you're expected to be looking for a job on the side.

Startups are great for generalists looking to get into a lot of different areas. You need to be more flexible in what you do, because the company may pivot and there might be attrition to where you need to pick up other people's jobs.

For evaluating startups, I would look at how much capital money they have raised to date on [www.crunchbase.com](http://www.crunchbase.com). It's possible that the company is already revenue positive and needs less venture funding, but this is rarer among startups. At small startups, there tends to be more mobility between teams and roles, so the position you're hired may not be what you end up during in the longer term.

Answer (score 0):

> Dark Matter: Are you paid well in your current internship?
>
> snorlax: Nope... We can consider I'm not.

Follow the money.

You have "graduated" so having an "internship" is actually a step down.  "A reputable company" almost by definition pays well so it can't be all that great.